# A class method which accepts lambda as parameter - error message

Tags: c++, lambda

I tried to create such method:

```
WeaponsDatabase
{
public:

    template<typename Functor> 
    QList<const WeaponData*> getSpecificWeapons(Functor criterium);
};
template<typename Functor>
QList<const WeaponData*> WeaponsDatabase::getSpecificWeapons(Functor criterium)
{
    QList<const WeaponData*> weaponsForCriterium;

    foreach (const WeaponData *weapon, weapons)
    {
        if (criterium(weapon))
        {
            weaponsForCriterium.append(weapon);
        }
    }

    return weaponsForCriterium;
}
```

seemed ok, and it compiled. Then I tried to use it elsewhere:

```
auto criterium = [hardpoint](const WeaponData *weapon)->bool
{
    return weapon->hardpoint == hardpoint;
};

WeaponsDatabase::getInstance().getSpecificWeapons(criterium);
```

it does not work, and I don't understand the error message. Can you mates help me with explanation?

```
In file included from ..\equipmentgroupwidget.cpp:3:0:
..\weaponsdatabase.h:35:57: error: 'QList<const WeaponData*> WeaponsDatabase::getSpecificWeapons(Functor) [with Functor = EquipmentGroupWidget::EquipmentGroupWidget(const QString&, QWidget*)::<lambda(const WeaponData*)>]', declared using local type 'EquipmentGroupWidget::EquipmentGroupWidget(const QString&, QWidget*)::<lambda(const WeaponData*)>', is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
template<typename Functor> QList<const WeaponData*> getSpecificWeapons(Functor criterium);
```

Comment: Are there other compiler warnings/errors? Did you try to move the implementation of `getSpecificWeapons` into the class, directly to the declaration? Can you please provide an [mcve] so that we can try to reproduce?

Comment: Ad trying to move definition to the class - nope. About that example hmmm might be problematic, but I'll try.

Comment: Mods, how can I mark this thread as answered and solved, and give Werner Henze a reputation point?

Comment: If you have a solution, just write an answer and accept it. Or delete the question.

Comment: @WernerHenze I can't accept my own post :/ Therefore I'm asking you to write your advices as full answer, as moving the definition into the class helped me.

Comment: You can accept your own answer. I think you might need to wait a day or two before doing that, but it's definitely allowed.

Comment: Do we really not already have a canonical “templates (usually) must be defined in header files” question?

Comment: Just to be clear: my proposal to move the implementation of `getSpecificWeapons` into the class declaration was not meant to be the right way to do it. The code that you showed looks good - assuming that the implementation of `getSpecificWeapons` was in the header file. If it was not, then move the definition of `getSpecificWeapons` to the header file (no need for it to be inside the class declaration). If it was, then I don't understand it and you might face a compiler error.

Comment: The implementation of getSpecificWeapons was in .cpp file before, moving it into definition of the class helped. But your other note, to move it outside, but still in the .h file is also right. Thank you very much mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits for @WernerHenze- moving the implementation into the class solved the problem. Thank you very much mate.